# Multiple edit text field

Tags: php, javascript, html, web-services, web

Im trying to modify the following code so it can save for multiple edited text while at the moment this code only saving one (first) edited text ... could anybody please modify this code for me say for example: you modify it to save 3 or 4 edited text, and based on that I can add any number of text field I need.
and onother thing to menstion when if you write in text fild, saved it and then refresh the page your written contents will still there same as if you try with the following code with one text field, I want this featear also applied when adding multiple text fields.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Allowing Users to Edit Multiple Text field and save the contents</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function saveEdits() {

//get the editable element
var editElem = document.getElementById("edit");

//get the edited element content
var userVersion = editElem.innerHTML;

//save the content to local storage
localStorage.userEdits = userVersion;

//write a confirmation to the user
document.getElementById("update").innerHTML="Edits saved!";

}
function checkEdits() {

//find out if the user has previously saved edits
if(localStorage.userEdits!=null)
    document.getElementById("edit").innerHTML=localStorage.userEdits;
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="checkEdits()">

<div id="edit" contenteditable="true">
Here is the element's original content
</div>

<input type="button" value="save my edits" onclick="saveEdits()"/>

<div id="update"> Edit the text and click to save for next time</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in Advance.

this is what i've tried.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Allowing Users to Edit Multiple Text field and save the contents</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function saveEdits() {

//get the editable element
var editElem = document.getElementById("edit");

//get the edited element content
var userVersion = editElem.innerHTML;

//save the content to local storage
localStorage.userEdits = userVersion;

// for new text field
localStorage.userEdit1 = userVersion;
//write a confirmation to the user
document.getElementById("update").innerHTML="Edits saved!";

}
function checkEdits() {

//find out if the user has previously saved edits
if(localStorage.userEdits!=null)
    document.getElementById("edit").innerHTML=localStorage.userEdits;
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="checkEdits()">

<div id="edit" contenteditable="true">
Here is the element's original content
</div>

    <!--New text field -->
    <div id="edit" contenteditable="true">
This is another text field.
</div>

<input type="button" value="save my edits" onclick="saveEdits()"/>

<div id="update"> Edit the text and click to save for next time</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think I have to do like this:

Comment: localStorage.userEdit1 = userVersion;
localStorage.userEdit2 = userVersion;
.......

Comment: and so on ... but not really sure and have tried it but it doesn't working

Comment: also i add this line in body ...

Comment: <div id="edit" contenteditable="true">
Here is the element's original content
</div>

Comment: it creates new field, but when press saveedits and then refresh the page it just saving content of first field and the rest not saved.

Comment: you can not use the same id more than once. It's an identifier after all, so with double id's it is impossible to identify an element.

Answer (score 1):

Dirty copy paste job. At least it demonstrates how to add more editable divs.

To make it dynamic, you may cnosider to construct the function a bit differently, or start adding jQuery in it to make the element selection easier..

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Allowing Users to Edit Multiple Text field and save the contents</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function saveEdits() {

//get the editable element
var editElem1 = document.getElementById("edit1");
var editElem2 = document.getElementById("edit2");
var editElem3 = document.getElementById("edit3");
var editElem4 = document.getElementById("edit4");

//get the edited element content
var userVersion1 = editElem1.innerHTML;
var userVersion2 = editElem2.innerHTML;
var userVersion3 = editElem3.innerHTML;
var userVersion4 = editElem4.innerHTML;

//save the content to local storage
localStorage.userEdits1 = userVersion1;
localStorage.userEdits2 = userVersion2;
localStorage.userEdits3 = userVersion3;
localStorage.userEdits4 = userVersion4;

//write a confirmation to the user
document.getElementById("update").innerHTML="Edits saved!";

}
function checkEdits() {

//find out if the user has previously saved edits
if(localStorage.userEdits1!=null)
    document.getElementById("edit1").innerHTML=localStorage.userEdits1;

if(localStorage.userEdits2!=null)
    document.getElementById("edit2").innerHTML=localStorage.userEdits2;

if(localStorage.userEdits3!=null)
    document.getElementById("edit3").innerHTML=localStorage.userEdits3;


if(localStorage.userEdits4!=null)
    document.getElementById("edit4").innerHTML=localStorage.userEdits4;
}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="checkEdits()">

<div id="edit1" contenteditable="true">
Here is the element's original content
</div>
<div id="edit2" contenteditable="true">
Here is the element's original content
</div>
<div id="edit3" contenteditable="true">
Here is the element's original content
</div>
<div id="edit4" contenteditable="true">
Here is the element's original content
</div>
<input type="button" value="save my edits" onclick="saveEdits()"/>

<div id="update"> Edit the text and click to save for next time</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: first of Thanks Moe for your help ... and socondly Im sorry tht i forgot to mention the reference and tutorial of this code is this link:http://www.developerdrive.com/2012/06/allowing-users-to-edit-text-content-with-html5/